# Почему отношение — халатное?

Tags: фразеология

О небрежном отношении к работе говорят "халатность". А при чем тут халат? Откуда пошло выражение?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

С середины XIX в. у относит. прилагат. *халатный* появляется переносное качественное значение: `небрежно-безразличный и недобросовестный, неряшливо-нерадивый` (к работе, к выполнению обязанностей), например, «халатное отношение к работе».

Семантическая эволюция имени прилагательного халатный началась в 30—40-е гг. XIX в. До этого времени в дворянской культуре халат лишь воспевался, например, И. М. Долгоруковым, П. А. Вяземским как символ русского барства с его ленью и небрежной распущенностью. Халат был типичной домашней одеждой помещика и чиновника, в которую они были облачены большую часть дня. Мелкие же чиновники, подьячие, мещане и семинаристы считали халат своим парадным, выходным одеянием.

Характерно в фельетоне славянофила И. С. Аксакова («Письма в редакцию ”Дня“», 1863) такое рассуждение о типах старых и новых петербургских тайных советников Российской империи:
«Разница между ними та, что у ”старых“ из-под мундира виден — халат, и хотя халат вещь вовсе некрасивая и в некотором роде даже неприличная, но, право, глаз, утомленный блеском шитья и пуговиц или однообразным цветом мундирного платья, не без удовольствия отдыхает на пестрой ткани халата! халат — это ведь эмблема лени, бесцеремонности, простоты, — это все же, сравнительно с форменными чувствами, нечто сердечное и человечное. У ”молодых“ нет ничего, кроме вицмундира — сшитого, конечно, у лучшего Французского портного... не только не видать халата, но, кажется, сама голландская рубашка глядит вицмундиром...» (Аксаков, Славянофильство и западничество, с. 118—119).

Слова *халатный, халатность* еще в 80—90-х гг. XIX в. воспринимались консервативными, пуристически настроенными кругами общества как неологизмы, как новообразования.

Затем Гоголь в "Мёртвых душах" добавил  слову значение "распущенный, лениво-недобросовестный". Тогда же было образовано слово *халатность*.
Например, В. П. Боткин писал А. А. Фету (28 августа 1862): «Да и нравится нам во французском образовании то, что составляет дурные его стороны, именно распущенность его, халатность...» (Фет, Воспоминания, ч. 1, с. 402).
В наше время экспрессии прибавилось.
[ХАЛАТНЫЙ, ХАЛАТНОСТЬ | etymolog.ruslang.ru](http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vinogradov.php?id=halatnij_halatnost&vol=1)

Answer (score 2):

ХАЛАТНЫЙ перен., устар. спокойный, ленивый, неповоротливый ◆ Кифа Мокиевич человек нрава кроткого… проводил жизнь халатным образом.(Н.В.Гоголь)
(словарь Ушакова)

По-моему связь слова "халат" и устаревшей формы слова "халатность" очевидна, но это лишь моя догадка, возможно есть и другие варианты.